# How to generate Bearer Token using C# REST API Authenticate with Bearer Token?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-webjobs

I am trying to create webjob to execute Token end point and generate the bearer token and execute Graph End Point to Query graph? How can I achive the same using C# REST Api? What is token end point? Following is the screenshot for token genrated in Postman tool.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What is token end point?

```
https://login.windows.net/<tenant-id>/oauth2/token
```

---

> How can I achive the same using C# REST Api?

If you want to use Resource Owner Password Credentials Grant in Azure AD OAuth, you may get the answer from this [blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wushuai/2016/09/25/resource-owner-password-credentials-grant-in-azure-ad-oauth/). The following is the snippet from the blog.

**Note:**

1. Furthermore, notice that resource owner password grant doesn't provide consent and **doesn't support** MFA either
2. Please test with **native** [Azure AD application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-create-service-principal-portal#create-an-azure-active-directory-application).
3. Add the user as the Application owner

> The following are the parameters needed in Azure AD OAuth for resource owner
>
> password grant.
>
> Name
>
> Description
>
> grant_type - The OAuth 2 grant type: password
>
> resource - The app to consume the token, such as Microsoft Graph, Azure AD Graph or your own Restful service
>
> client_id - The Client Id of a registered application in Azure AD
>
> username -The user account in Azure AD
>
> password -The password of the user account
>
> scope - optional, such as openid to get Id Tok

Demo code:

```
using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
{
  var tokenEndpoint = @"https://login.windows.net/<tenant-id>/oauth2/token";
  var accept = "application/json";

  client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", accept);
  string postBody = @"resource=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2F
  &client_id=<client id>
  &grant_type=password
  &username=xxx@xxx.onmicrosoft.com
  &password=<password>
  &scope=openid";

  using (var response = await client.PostAsync(tokenEndpoint, new StringContent(postBody, Encoding.UTF8, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")))
  {
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
      var jsonresult = JObject.Parse(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
      token = (string)jsonresult["access_token"];
    }
  }
}
```

[image]

**Updated:**

According to your comment, I also do a demo with RestClient.

```
var tenantId = "xxxxxx";
var client = new RestClient("https://login.windows.net/");
var request = new RestRequest($"{tenantId}/oauth2/token", Method.POST);
//// easily add HTTP Headers
request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json");
string postBody = @"resource=https://graph.microsoft.com/&client_id=xxxxx&grant_type=password&username=xxxxx&password=xxxxx&scope=openid";
request.AddParameter("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", postBody, ParameterType.RequestBody); //add request text body 
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
var content = response.Content;
var token = JObject.Parse(content)["access_token"];
```

Test result:
[image]

Comment: I want to use REST Client

Comment: Thanks for answer