# Need to generate Azure AD bearer token using C# rest call

Tags: c#, azure, azure-active-directory, bearer-token, azure-security

I want to generate a Azure AD bearer token via C# REST call. I want to write the user registration logic inside an API call. I am using this as token endpoint :

**https://login.windows.net/[tenant-id]/oauth2/token**

I followed the same procedure as described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48262975/how-to-generate-bearer-token-using-c-sharp-rest-api-authenticate-with-bearer-tok) article.

The user credential I am using is a "Global Administrator".

But I am still getting 'Unauthorized' error. Please find the code snippet and response body below-

**Code**

```
using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        {
            var tokenEndpoint = @"https://login.windows.net/<tanent-name>/oauth2/token";
            var accept = "application/json";

            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", accept);
            string postBody = @"resource=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2F
              &client_id=<client-id>
              &grant_type=password
              &username=<admin-user-name>
              &password=<admin-pass>
              &scope=openid";

            using (var response = await client.PostAsync(tokenEndpoint, new StringContent(postBody, Encoding.UTF8, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")))
            {
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    var jsonresult = JObject.Parse(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
                    var token = (string)jsonresult["access_token"];
                    return token;
                }
                else
                    return null;
            }
        }
```

**Response Body**

```
{ StatusCode: 401, ReasonPhrase: 'Unauthorized',
  Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
{
  Pragma: no-cache
  Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
  X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
  x-ms-request-id: cabefe46-ff73-4659-80a2-2f4136200900
  Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache
  P3P: CP="DSP CUR OTPi IND OTRi ONL FIN"
  Set-Cookie: esctx=AQABAAAAAADX8GCi6Js6SK82TsD2Pb7...
  Set-Cookie: x-ms-gateway-slice=004; path=/; secure; HttpOnly
  Set-Cookie: stsservicecookie=ests; path=/; secure; HttpOnly
  Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
  X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
  Date: Thu, 24 May 2018 13:43:39 GMT
  Content-Length: 457
  Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
  Expires: -1
}}
```

**P.S.-** Also please point out if there is any other way of adding new user without doing the REST call. I don't want to have user registration in the client application.

[Update] Please find the screenshot of added permissions and roles.
[image: Permissions and Roles]

Comment: Any particular reason for not using [ADAL.NET](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-dotnet)?

Comment: 401 error it means that you have no permission to do that. Which API you want to access?  The [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48262975/how-to-generate-bearer-token-using-c-sharp-rest-api-authenticate-with-bearer-tok) you mentioned is that to operate Microsoft Graph API. For different APIs, the resources are diferent. More information about which API you want to operate will be more helpful.

Comment: Since you're using ROPC grant flow, Is that user owner of that client(AAD Application)?

Comment: I am trying to use the Graph API to add a new user. Please check the updated screenshots for added roles and permissions.

Comment: @evilSnobu I have no reason for not using ADAL.NET. Can you please give me an example how to create user by ADAL.NET in the API itself ?

Comment: Drop that URL in your browser first, you should get a one time consent screen.

Comment: Hi @evilSnobu tried that. Getting this error "AADSTS90056: This endpoint only accepts POST, OPTIONS requests. Received a GET request.".

Comment: Right. Should be `login.microsoftonline.com` instead. Click that Grant Consent button in [Step 6](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-dotnet). I see you're using App Permissions, i don't think the password flow needs that, most probably needs delegated permissions. To use app permissions you need to switch to client credential flow (app id and app secret). That's fully supported in ADAL.

Answer (score 0):

As Tom mentioned, your issue shoud be caused by the user doesn't have permission to your App.

**Since you're using ROPC grant flow, make sure that the user is the owner of that Client/AAD App.**

You can add onwer to the AAD app:

Go to Azure portal > Azure Acitve Directory > Application Registration > The App > Settings > Owners > Add owner > Select that user.

Additonal, if the user has enabled MFA, this flow won't work.

Let me know if it helps!

Comment: Hi @Wayne, I have added this user as the owner of the application. But its still giving the same error. Please find the updated screenshots for reference.

Comment: Hi @Sudip . What is the kind of your App?

Comment: I am testing with a Console application (.NET 4.6). Later I will move the code to a Web API logic.

Comment: Um... you'd better register your app with Native app.

Comment: Ok.. will try that. I will keep you posted.

Comment: Also, I'm not 100% sure ROPC flow should needs delegated permissions. Try to add delegated permissions and click grant permissions.

Answer (score 0):

> Also please point out if there is any other way of adding new user without doing the REST call. I don't want to have user registration in the client application.

If you want to create user, we could use the [Microsoft.Graph](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Graph) to do that.

Before that we need to [registry the Azure AD application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-create-service-principal-portal#create-an-azure-active-directory-application). And add the Microsoft graph permission. For more details we could refer to the [Create User API](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/user_post_users).

I test it with **Directory.ReadWrite.All** permission. Don't forget to **Grant permissions.**

[image]

Demo code.

```
string graphResourceId = "https://graph.microsoft.com/";
string authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{0}";
string tenantId = "tenant Id";
string clientId = "client Id";
string secret = "secret";
authority = String.Format(authority, tenantId);
AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority);
var accessToken = authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(graphResourceId, new ClientCredential(clientId, secret)).Result.AccessToken;
            var graphserviceClient = new GraphServiceClient(
                new DelegateAuthenticationProvider(
                    requestMessage =>
                    {
                        requestMessage.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", accessToken);

                        return Task.FromResult(0);
                    }));
var user = new User
         {
             UserPrincipalName = "tomaccount1@xxxxx.onmicrosoft.com",
             AccountEnabled = true,
             DisplayName = "tom1",
             PasswordProfile = new PasswordProfile
             {
                 ForceChangePasswordNextSignIn = true,
                 Password = "1234qweA!@#$%6"
             },
              MailNickname = "tomaccount1"
            };
 var addUserResult = graphserviceClient.Users.Request().AddAsync(user).Result;
```

**Test Result:**

[image]

**Check from Azure AD**

[image]

Packages.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="Microsoft.Graph" version="1.9.0" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Graph.Core" version="1.9.0" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory" version="3.19.4" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="11.0.2" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="System.IO" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="System.Net.Http" version="4.3.3" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="System.Runtime" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms" version="4.3.1" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="System.Security.Cryptography.Encoding" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="System.Security.Cryptography.Primitives" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net471" />
  <package id="System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates" version="4.3.2" targetFramework="net471" />
</packages>
```

Comment: Thanks but kinda stuck into something right now. Will try this definitely and keep you posted.