# oAuth2 - AADSTS90009 : Issue in connecting Azure Active Directory

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I am getting below error while connecting to Azure Active Directory

"AADSTS90009: Application 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' is requesting a token for itself. This scenario is supported only if resource is specified using the GUID based App Identifier.

Comment: Please add more information about what you are trying to do and your current Azure AD configuration (app registration, permissions, etc.). Given the error, it seems that you are requesting an access token for an application (resource equal to App ID URI) by using the same application as client.

Comment: Hi.. I got the below information from the AAD Configuration Team, calling the token URL using Postman

Comment: Hi.. I got the below information from the AAD Configuration Team, calling the token URL using Postman      https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}/oauth2/token
grant_type:"password"
client_id:"XXXXXX"   (Application ID)
username:"giri@xx.com"
password:"XXXX"
resource:"XXXXX" (Application ID URI)
client_secret:"XXXXXXX"

Comment: Application Type : Web APP API

Comment: Is that you want to use web app to call you web API?

Comment: yes. Web application want to use Azure Web API type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use web application to call web API, please refer to the [sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-webapi-openidconnect-aspnetcore). The detailed steps.

1. Register your Web API application in Azure Portal. For more details, please refer to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-v1-add-azure-ad-app).
2. Register your Web app application in Azure Portal
3. Grant permission.(add you web API application in you web app application)

   a. select you web application
   b. set permissions.
      [image]
      [image]
      [image]
      [image]
4. Get access token

   Method : POST

   URL :  https://login.microsoftonline.com/ [Directory ID]/oauth2/token

   Headers

   Cache-Control : no-cache
   Content-Type : application/x-www-form-urlencoded

   Body

   grant_type : password
   resource : Your App ID URI
   client_id : [application id]
   client_secret : [key value]
   username : [account name]
   password : [Password]

Answer (score 0):

The error information indicates that you are using Azure AD application url as resource.

As qwe mentioned that you need to use the WebApp API(Not Azure AD application) you wanted to access as resource. For more information please refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v1-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow#example).

```
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}/oauth2/token 

Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

grant_type=client_credentials&client_id={clientId}&client_secret={secret key}=&resource={resourceaddress}
```

[image]

**Note：** If we want to use the OAuth 2 `grant type: password`, we need to registry Azure AD **native** application. For more information please refer to another [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48262975/how-to-generate-bearer-token-using-c-sharp-rest-api-authenticate-with-bearer-tok).

Answer (score -1):

This error is saying that the field you provided in the resource parameter is requesting tokens for itself.

Alternatively, you can provide an app ID URI of a web API you've registered or another resource with scopes to get tokens for that resource (Microsoft Graph, Office API, etc).